# How to know if both the checkbox is selected

Tags: wpf

I am making a wpf form where there is a question and user will select yes or no checkbox. Now I need to put few conditions so that:

```
1. User has to select YES or NO, which means the question cannot be left empty
2. User cannot select both YES or NO, which means only YES or NO has to be selected
3. If user selects YES, then save the option and proceed further
4. If user selects NO, then save the option and proceed further
```

Now for this what I am doing is:

```
//Just for the tesing purpose, I am using message box to show what user has selected

//If user has selected YES
if (yes.IsChecked == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show(" Yes checked");
}
//If user has selected NO
if (no.IsChecked == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show("No checked");
}
//If user has not selected any option
if (yes.IsChecked == false && no.IsChecked == false)
{
      MessageBox.Show("please select option");
}
//If user has selected both the options
if (yes.IsChecked == true && no.IsChecked == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show("cannot select both options");
}
```

This is not working as expected because if user selects both the check boxes, then it shows

```
Yes checked, then
No checked, then
cannot select both options
```

Which is the best method to accomplish above conditions.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an OR situation you should use a radio button not a check box. It removes the need for you to write your own validation method to check for both being selected as only one at a time is possible, you then only need to check that something has been selected and just save that selection.

Comment: I will try with radio button

Answer (score 0):

Could you just force the other option clear if one box is checked?

```
//If user has selected YES
if (yes.IsChecked == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show(" Yes checked");
     // Ensure that 'no' is not checked
     no.IsChecked = false;
}

//If user has selected NO
if (no.IsChecked == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show("No checked");
     // Ensure that 'yes' is not checked
     yes.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: No because in this case if user selects both the option `YES NO` then initially yes will processed and then it will automatically clear the NO option because it is set to false and the message that "you have selected both the options" will not come

Comment: I don't know why you want to give the user the option to select both and enter an error condition, but ok.  I'd suggest going with Kamikazi's answer.

Comment: I guess there should be an error condition if the user has selected both the option. I mean there has to be single result for a question either yes or no. But definitely I'll try with radio button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the tests with the ^ operator:

```
if (yes.IsChecked ^ no.IsChecked)
{
    // proceed, as exactly one is checked
}
```

Optionally you can test if both are checked:

```
if (yes.IsChecked && no.IsChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("cannot select both options");
}
```

And as last option you can test if both are unchecked:

```
if (!yes.IsChecked && !no.IsChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("please select option");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to Rearrange your if conditions

```
 //If user has not selected any option
 if (yes.IsChecked == false && no.IsChecked == false)
 {
   MessageBox.Show("please select option");
 }
 //If user has selected both the options
 else if (yes.IsChecked == true && no.IsChecked == true)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("cannot select both options");
 }
 //If user has selected YES
 else if (yes.IsChecked == true)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(" Yes checked");
 }
 //If user has selected NO
 else if (no.IsChecked == true)
 {
   MessageBox.Show("No checked");
 }
```

Comment: @SAndrew any reason?

Comment: If user has selected both the options then it will first show cannot select both option and then yes checked and no checked

Comment: @SAndrew no it will show only one output you should check it in detail

Comment: Ohh didnt catch it in the first time.  Great. Will try it